# ANDROID STUDIO: How do I fix my ScrollView?

Tags: java, android, xml, scrollview

**Newbie in android studio here**.

I am trying to make **a list of local herbal plants a-z** and also had a thought if I would just make another tab for each letter of the first letter of the plant. And then i realized that i can make a scrollview. so its quite late for me to insert the scrollview and i know it would make a problem at my code.

now that i have put it in my .xml file, **my app is forced to close everytime I run it.**

how do I fix this? **Thanks!!**

(heres the code):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.mobprog.herbalite.MainActivity">
    
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/abaniko_pic"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="145dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/stroke"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/kjadhskjadhsa"


            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"

            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.022"
        />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/abanico_text"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/stroke"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Abaniko"

            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20dp"

            app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"

            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/abaniko_pic"

            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.013"

        />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/alim_pic"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="145dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/stroke"

            android:padding="5dp"

            app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"


            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.950"

            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/alim"
        />

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/alim_text"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/stroke"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:text="Alim"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"

            android:textSize="20dp"


            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.941"

            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

             app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/alim_pic"
         />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/alinang_pic"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="145dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="195dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/stroke"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"


            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.022"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

            app:srcCompat="@drawable/alinang"
        />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/alinang_text"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/stroke"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:text="Alinang"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"

            android:textSize="20dp"


            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.013"

            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/alinang_pic"
        />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ampalaya_pic"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="145dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="195dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/stroke"

            android:padding="5dp"

            app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"


            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.938"

            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ampalaya" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ampalaya_text"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/stroke"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"

            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Ampalaya"
            android:textAlignment="center"

            android:textColor="#000000"


            android:textSize="20dp"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"

            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.928"

            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ampalaya_pic"
        />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ambal_pic"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="145dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="385dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/stroke"

            android:padding="5dp"

            app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"


            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.048"

            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ambal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ambal_text"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/stroke"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"

            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Ambal"
            android:textAlignment="center"

            android:textColor="#000000"


            android:textSize="20dp"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"

            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.013"

            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ambal_pic" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/anabo_pic"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="145dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="385dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/stroke"

            android:padding="5dp"

            app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"


            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.938"

            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/anabo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/anabo_text"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/stroke"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"

            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Anabo"
            android:textAlignment="center"

            android:textColor="#000000"


            android:textSize="20dp"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"

            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.928"

            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/anabo_pic" />

    </ScrollView>
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: can you share the crash report that causes your app closes?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set parent layout as linear layout in scrollview.

like this

```
  <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

           //set here all you child widgets

 </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```